# What is the origin of "bite me"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, offensive-language, euphemisms, minced-oaths

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning and usage of “bite me”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27753/meaning-and-usage-of-bite-me)

Here’s the dilemma: What body part does the oft-used expression, “Bite me!” refer to?

All the males (man on the street) I’ve surveyed, say the bum, the tushie, indeed, the derriere. Most women don't know and profess to never use this expression. I've had a few varied answers, but I’d say 85% so far agree that’s it’s the human posterior.

Is there any relation or association with the Bard’s “I bite my thumb at you, Sir”?

Comment: @Mitch: I flagged the other as a duplicate of this. They are definitely the same question and topic, but I think the answers are better on this one.